# glibc 2.3 in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, ati, graphics, glibc

I'm a very new Ubuntu user, and I'm having some issues with my graphics card.  I'm running 13.10 and the graphics are quite slow and glitchy, and my laptop won't wake up after suspend.  I also am getting a VERY short battery life.

Much googling revealed that my system is not using my graphics card at all.

sudo lshw -c video had this to say:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:53 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0300000-f033ffff
```

It seems to me that installing AMD Catalyst drivers would help, and only the newset latest greatest version (13.12) would support my card (I can't ascertain for sure but it seems my laptop uses an AMD Radeon HD 7640G card).  Problem is, that version says it requires glibc 2.2 or 2.3.  When I do "lld --version" it returns:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.17-93ubuntu4) 2.17
```

No good.  So I need a different version of glibc.  But I can't seem to find any info anywhere on how to install it on my OS.  apt-get and synaptic package manager tell me that the latest version is 2.17.  Is an earlier version unsafe with Ubuntu 13.10?  Should I not be doing this at all?

BTW: If I've made a mistake and the AMD Catalyst driver is not the way to go, please let me know, and if there is another option...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this will fix your issue, but it did help me: http://linuxg.net/fix-slow-graphics-performance-on-ubuntu-13-04-intel-gpu/